# Browser lookup returns a wrong browser when Chrome dev console is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I am using this code to identify users' browsers. It works great when I just load a page in Chrome, however, when I open the Chrome developer console, it returns "Safari" even though it is still Google Chrome. Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
var browser = (function (agent) {
                    switch (true) {
                        case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1:
                            return "Edge";
                        case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1:
                            return "chromium based edge (dev or canary)";
                        case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr:
                            return "Opera";
                        case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome:
                            return "Chrome";
                        case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1:
                            return "ie";
                        case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1:
                            return "Firefox";
                        case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1:
                            return "Safari";
                        default:
                            return "Other";
                    }
                })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
                console.log('User\'s browser is: ', browser);
```

TIA!

RESOLVED: disable responsive IPAD view in chorme!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9jg.jpg)

Comment: It is returning chrome only. Checked in Chrome 83. Which version of chrome browser you are using?

Comment: Please disable the responsive move if you've enabled that. https://prnt.sc/swhwxp
You can use `ctrl+m` or `cmd+m` to disable responsive view. I think you've opened that in iphone or ipad responsive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that's because you have selected iPad Pro as device, which changes your user agent. Try setting it to Responsive and it should work properly. :)

[image: select Responsive instead of iPad Pro here]

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the responsive mode if you've enabled that.
[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/swhwxp)

You can use `ctrl+m` or `cmd+m` to disable responsive view. I think you've opened that in iphone or ipad responsive mode.